# href base url not being attached

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying to create a button on a visual force page that takes you to the create new case page. We are in a sandbox environment and we would like to use a relative url and not a hardcoded url so we don't have to fix the urls when we promote the package to production.

Any ideas on how to attach the base url?

```
<input type="button" class="btn" value="New Case" href="/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Case"/>
```

Comment: Read the documentation on [HTML input tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp), `href` is not a supported property.

Comment: Have you tried using -  {!$Site.Prefix}/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the $Action binding?
`<apex:commandButton value="New Case" action={!URLFOR($Action.Case.New)} />`

This will ensure your link is valid in any org, sandbox or prod.

Comment: And regardless if a record type first needs to be selected, either!

Comment: I like this implementation. Really helps having it work across environments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location='/001'"/>
```

Replacing the '/001' with the relative URL you need. I do not think that href on a regular HTML tag will be rendered with the relative url.

Answer (score 0):

If your buttons are already heavily styled, you could use css + an anchor tag to mimic a button

```
<a class="btn" href="/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Case">New Case</a>
```

It isn't perfect but it will accomplish your goal without JavaScript or an apex tag.